# How to properly format a multiline sum under which there is a multiline condition?

Tags: spacing, align

I have the following equations:

```
    \begin{flalign*}
    \text{Runtime} & = \underset{\begin{subarray}{c}
                    v \in V(T_1)\\
                    w \in C_\alpha(v)
                  \end{subarray}}{\sum}\big(|child(v)| + |child(w)| + \\
                  & \quad\quad\quad \underset{P_k \in P(child(v), child(w))}{\sum}|P_k|\big)\\
    & < \underset{\begin{subarray}{c}
                    v \in V(T_1)\\
                    w \in C_\alpha(v)
                  \end{subarray}}{\sum}(deg(T_1) + deg(T_2) + deg(T_1) deg(T_2))\\
    & = O(N_1 deg(T_1) deg(T_2)^{\alpha + 1})
    \end{flalign*}
```

This produces the following output.
[image: Output from latex]

The first sum in the equation is badly formatted. There is too much gap in between lines when it is broken down into two lines. I want it formatted with reduced space in first and second line like the following figure:

[image]

How can I acheive this?

Comment: try writing `\\[-0.3cm]` (or some other negative distance) instead of ``\\`` in the first line

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd like to suggest the following code. Note a few changes:

1. `\sum_{\substack{}}` instead of `\overset{...}{\sum}` which is too wordy.
2. `deg()` and `child()` are looking better if typeset using upright font shape (in italic they look as bunches of variables)
3. I think it'd be better not to split the first line at all. Though, if it's too long, splitting the subscript for the second sum and adding several negative spaces helps a bit.
4. `\Big` parentheses help with visual identification of what is to sum.

   ```
   \documentclass{article}
   \usepackage{amsmath}
   \DeclareMathOperator{\Deg}{deg}
   \DeclareMathOperator{\child}{child}
   \begin{document}
   \begin{flalign*}
   \text{Runtime} & = \sum_{\substack{v\in V(T_1)\\w\in C_\alpha(v)}}
               \!\!\!\Big(\left|\child(v)\right| + \left|\child(w)\right| +
                 \!\!\!\!\!\!\sum_{\substack{P_k \in 
   P(\child(v),\\\phantom{P_k \in P(}\child(w))}}
             \!\!\!\!\!\!|P_k|\Big)\\
   & < \sum_{\substack{v\in V(T_1)\\w\in C_\alpha(v)}}(\Deg(T_1) + \Deg(T_2) 
   + \Deg(T_1) \Deg(T_2))\\
   & = O(N_1 \Deg(T_1) \Deg(T_2)^{\alpha + 1})
   \end{flalign*}
   \end{document}
   ```

The result is [image: Flalign example]

Answer (score 2):

Some small improvements, using `\smashoperator` from `mathtools` (no need to load `masmath` if you load mathtools):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Deg}{deg}
\DeclareMathOperator{\child}{child}

\begin{document}

\begin{flalign*}
\text{Runtime} & = \smashoperator{\sum_{\substack{v\in V(T_1)\\w\in C_\alpha(v)}}}
           \Big(\left|\child(v)\right| + \left|\child(w)\right| +
             \smashoperator{ \sum_{\substack{P_k \in\\P(\child(v),\child(w))}}}
          |P_k|\Big)\\
& < \smashoperator{\sum_{\substack{v\in V(T_1)\\w\in C_\alpha(v)}}}\bigl(\Deg(T_1) + \Deg(T_2)
+ \Deg(T_1) \Deg(T_2)\bigr)\\
& = O\bigl(N_1 \Deg(T_1) \Deg(T_2)^{\alpha + 1}\bigr)
\end{flalign*}

\end{document}
```

[image]